# Flushing entire cache at once with Enterprise Caching Block

Tags: caching, .net-3.5, enterprise-library

I am looking into using Enterprise Caching Block for my .NET 3.5 service to cache a bunch of static data from the database.

From everything I have read, it seems that FileDependency is the best option for storing static data that does not expire too often. However, when the file changes and the cache is flushed, I need to get a callback once to do some post processing for that particular cache. If I implement ICacheItemRefreshAction and register it during adding an item to the cache, I get a callback for each one of them.

Is there a way to register a callback for the entire cache so that I dont see thousands of callbacks being invoked when the cache flushes?

Thanks

Comment: As a followup, is there a better way than using FileDependency for caching static data from the database. For example, if I want to cache a list of countries and their currency codes that we support and resides on the database. This data does not change unless we manually insert a new entry in the database. Is there a better way dependency I can use to trigger a change and flush the cache?

Answer (score 0):

To address your follow up for a better way than FileDependency: you could wrap a [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) in an ICacheItemExpiration.  See [SqlCacheDependency with the Caching Application Block](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/72118) for sample code.

That approach would only work with SQL Server and would require setting up Service Broker.

In terms of a cache level callback, I don't see an out of the box way to achieve that; almost everything is geared to the item level.  What you could do would be to create your own CacheManager Implementation that features a cache level callback.

Another approach might be to have a ICacheItemRefreshAction that only performs any operations when the cache is empty (i.e. the last item has been removed).